# How can I get the ESSID name only that I connected with?

Tags: command-line, wireless

I tried `$iwconfig | grep wlan0` but all I got was the line that my connected ESSID name exists. But I need only the name.

How do I get just the name?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but try this:

For the essid name:

```
iwconfig wlan0 2> /dev/null | awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

For the access point mode (as requested in the comment):

```
iwconfig wlan0 2> /dev/null | awk -F: '/Mode:/ {print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

For the link Quality (as requested in the comment):

```
iwconfig wlan0 2> /dev/null | awk -F= '/Quality/ {print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

For the channel, (as requested in the comment) try this:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning essid ESSID | grep Channel | head -1 | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

Make sure to replace ESSID with your essid:

For the address, (as requested in the comment) try this:

```
ifconfig wlan0 2> /dev/null | awk -F: '/inet\ addr/ {print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: That's perfect.

Comment: Can you help me to find another informations.
(channel connection,mode of my Access Point,Quality,

Comment: yeah, sure, ill add them to the answer above, i'm about to leave now, but ill add them later on

Comment: all worked except the channel's coomand

Comment: My bad, make sure to replace "ESSID" with your own essid!

Comment: yes I understood. can you help me to find my network address ?

Comment: done, ans eddited

Answer (score 3):

After toying around with tons of different commands, flags, greps, trims, awks, and seds, I finally settled on:

```
iwgetid -r
```

Simple and clean.  This will output the SSID and nothing more.  Previously, I was using this clunker:

```
iwconfig <iface> | grep ESSID | awk -F: '{print $2}' | sed 's/\"//g'
```

One of my favorite things about the *nix world is the ability to string together a bunch of commands and programs that utilize standard input and output to achieve whatever it is that I need.  However, when a single flag can be passed to a program like **iwgetid** to accomplish the same thing, it's no longer a decision between which to use.  It's an IQ test.

Keep in mind you can still specify different wireless network interfaces using **iwgetid** like so:

```
iwgetid <iface> -r
```